# How to parse and print an XML file using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to parse an XML file using Ruby. It parses successfully but it does not print what I want it to print:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

def parseXML(filename)
  page = Nokogiri::XML(open(filename))
  puts page.class

page.css('//ssn//p').each do |a|

  puts  a['qn']

  page.css('//ssn//p//v').each do |e|

      puts e['fans']

      end
    end
  end

if __FILE__ == $0
  parseXML('CS 141 FALL 2016/SessionData/L1611021411.xml')
end
```

The format of the XML file is:

```
<ssn >
 <p strt="14:13:09" qn="Question 1" stp="14:14:20">
  <v fans="C" id="#00A4DB7F" ans="C" fanst="33.59"/>
  <v fans="A" id="#3910072E" ans="D" fanst="50.71"/>
  <v fans="A" id="#3C44F58D" ans="A" fanst="20.71"/>
  <v fans="B" id="#3C62633D" ans="B" fanst="10.78"/> 
   </p>
  <p strt="14:20:17" qn="Question 2" stp="14:21:24">
  <v fans="A" id="#00A4DB7F" ans="D" fanst="33.59"/>
  <v fans="E" id="#3910072E" ans="C" fanst="50.71"/>
  <v fans="E" id="#3C44F58D" ans="B" fanst="20.71"/>
  <v fans="C" id="#3C62633D" ans="A" fanst="10.78"/> 
    </p>
   <p strt="14:22:17" qn="Question 3" stp="14:23:24">
  <v fans="A" id="#00A4DB7F" ans="A" fanst="33.59"/>
  <v fans="B" id="#3910072E" ans="B" fanst="50.71"/>
  <v fans="C" id="#3C44F58D" ans="C" fanst="20.71"/>
  <v fans="D" id="#3C62633D" ans="D" fanst="10.78"/> 
    </p>
   </ssn>
```

I want to print:

```
Question 1: 
C 
A 
A 
B 

Question 2: 
A 
E 
E
C 

Question 3: 
A 
B 
C 
D
```

But instead it's printing this:

```
Question 1: 
C 
A 
A 
B 
A 
E 
E
C 
A 
B 
C 
D

Question 2: 
C 
A 
A 
B 
A 
E 
E
C 
A 
B 
C 
D

Question 3: 
C 
A 
A 
B 
A 
E 
E
C 
A 
B 
C 
D
```

Comment: When you ask a question it's really important that what is displayed accurately represents what problem you're asking about. That means formatting must be usable. Take the time to make it readable and accurate; The time you put in encourages us to help you. Help is available in the formatting pages for easy access.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you for your help. I'll work on it.

Comment: Note: When asking, we expect you to strip your input to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything beyond that wastes our time as we try to find a solution for you. "[mcve]" Yours isn't as bad as many we see, but it is a reason for closing questions, and again, the effort to help write clear and concise question is important.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your CSS selectors are not CSS, nor are they the correct XPath:

```
'//ssn//p'
'//ssn//p//v'
```

Nokogiri tests them prior to using them and thinks they're XPath so it treats them as XPath.

To get the output you want I'd use CSS:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<ssn>
  <p qn="Question 1">
    <v ans="C"/>
    <v ans="D"/>
    <v ans="A"/>
    <v ans="B"/> 
  </p>
  <p qn="Question 2">
    <v ans="D"/>
    <v ans="C"/>
    <v ans="B"/>
    <v ans="A"/> 
  </p>
  <p qn="Question 3">
    <v ans="A"/>
    <v ans="B"/>
    <v ans="C"/>
    <v ans="D"/> 
  </p>
</ssn>
EOT

doc.search('p').each { |p|
  puts "#{ p['qn'] }:"
  puts p.search('v').map { |v| v['ans'] }
  puts
}
```

Which generates:

```
Question 1:
C
D
A
B

Question 2:
D
C
B
A

Question 3:
A
B
C
D
```

The problem with the XPath selectors you're using is the secondary `//`. In XPath-ese `//` means start at the top of the document and search everywhere. So `//ssn//p` means "start at the top and find `<ssn>` then start at the top and find `<p>`. Instead you want `//ssn/p` which means "start at the top and find `<ssn>` then find `<p>` inside them".

The selectors above could have been written:

```
doc.search('//p').each { |p|
  puts "#{ p['qn'] }:"
  puts p.search('./v').map { |v| v['ans'] }
  puts
}
```

which would output the same thing.

I recommend using CSS because it generally results in more readable selectors, however sometimes I use XPath because it's more powerful.

Nokogiri has `search` and `at`; `at` is equivalent to `search('some selector').first`. Nokogiri will try to figure out if the selector is CSS or XPath for you if you use those. There are also CSS and XPath specific methods `css` and `xpath` are similar to `search` and `at_css` and `at_xpath` are the `at` versions. Based on the output you got it appears that Nokogiri only uses the `*css` or `*xpath` variants as hints, not as absolute descriptions of the type of the selector. I'll have to nose around in the code to see for sure.